# Flutter Pod install failed - 'Invalid `Podfile` file no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ios, flutter

I cloned the project for wearable
https://github.com/sbis04/flutter_os_wear

Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

 #  from /Volumes/Storage/Bottle/Wearables/flutter_os_wear/ios/Podfile:57
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #      unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
 >        FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
 #      end
 #  -------------------------------------------

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:301:in `rescue in block in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:295:in `block in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in `from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:259:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:200:in `podfile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:150:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2

Answer (score 1):

Try uncommenting this line platform :ios, '8.0' in ${PROJECT}/ios/Podfile and set it to a higher version (like 9.0).

Comment: it's already 9 I have updated to 10.0 but the error still persists

Comment: create new project and migrate this cloned repo into it and try to run it i think it should work then

Comment: umm ok I will try that

Comment: @AmarMaharjan did you solve it. Cause I have the same issue

Comment: @NaderKhaled try my answer it will work as it also worked for me